# Can I update a SharePoint document's metadata using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, metadata

I am using Graph to create folders and documents in SharePoint but can't figure out how to update the metadata for a document. Maybe it's not possible I can't seem to find any details on it.

I tried a patch command with the metadata in the Json message but it did not work

I can create files using this code so my authentication is ok.

```
    public static string UploadContent(string webApiUrl, string accessToken, byte[] data)
    {
        string s = String.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json");
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, accessToken);
                s = client.Encoding.GetString(client.UploadData(webApiUrl, "PUT", data));

            }
        }

        return s;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Once file uploaded, [`Update listItem` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) needs to be utilized to update the properties on a listItem, for example:

a)upload a file:

```
PUT  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{file-path}:/content
Body: file content
```

b)update list item:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{file-path}:/listItem/fields   
Content-Type: application/json
Body {
    "Title": "new title"
}
```

**C# example**

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json");
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, accessToken);

    //1.Upload a new file
    var requestUrl = $"/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/root:/{filePath}:/content";
    var result = client.UploadData(requestUrl, "PUT", contentBytes);

    //2.Set file metadata
    requestUrl = $"/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/root:/{filePath}:/listItem/fields";
    var fields = new { Title = "Sample video" };
    var fieldsPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fields);
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
    client.UploadString(requestUrl, "PATCH", fieldsPayload);

}
```